# How can I run multiple threads in JOMP on Windows (10) from either the command prompt or in Eclipse?

Tags: java, concurrency, openmp

I can't get multiple threads to run using JOMP no matter what I try. I actually can't run a JOMP program from the command line no matter what I try either in fact, although ironically it will compile from there and then run in Eclipse! Even in Eclipse though I only have one thread. I've been through the notes from my university course about installation of JOMP carefully, but they have not helped. I'll be more specific though:

Items in quotes below are from those notes:

1. "There are a couple of websites that tell you how to make jomp run under Eclipse, see http://www.lst.inf.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/ss10/24/ assignments/assignment_10/eclipse.txt"

This refers to a now broken link. It also seem to be the only link anyone on forums like Stackoverflow refer to when talking about this issue. Apparently it has instructions on runtime settings for Eclipse to allow multiple threads to run, but since the link is currently broken I can't access those valuable instructions.

2. "All that is required in order to do that is to ensure that jomp1.0b.jar is on the CLASSPATH"

I ran echo %CLASSPATH% at the command prompt to check if it was on the class path and got the following response:

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162\lib\jomp1.0b.jar

On my PC the jomp jar file is in that folder, so it appears I should be able to execute compiled JOMP programs from the command line, but unfortunately that is not the case. By executing one of these commands it should run:

java −Djomp.threads=2 parallel

java −Djomp.threads=2 -cp . parallel

java −Djomp.threads=2 -cp C:\Users\terry\eclipse-workspace\JOMPHello\src parallel

This is the folder the jomp, java and compiled class files are in. I also checked if "parallel" is the fully qualified class name in the way I have set it up in Eclipse, and it does appears to be. So running one of these commands should allow me to run the jomp program from the command line as near as I can tell, but they all return the following error:

Error: Could not find or load main class parallel
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: parallel

(To which I feel like telling Java, "You're not looking hard it enough! It is right in the folder I am running this command from!")

Clearly I am missing something. Can anyone tell me how to get JOMP programs running on the command line, or alternatively knows where there are accessible instructions for how to set up the work around runtime settings in Eclipse?

My implementation of the program seems to run with only one thread, so hopefully that means it is correct, but I can only be sure once I have run it with at least a few more threads.

Thanks,
Terry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to set up the runtime argument in Eclipse. You just have to add the following line into the VM Arguments box in under the Argument tab in Run Configurations for the file:

```
−Djomp.threads=n
```

(where n as before is the number of threads you want).

I'd still like to know why it's not working on the Command Line though. It makes me think my Java is set up weirdly.